# How to listen to form restarts? Application.Restart does not invoke the Form Constructor or Load and Shown event handlers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

After `Application.Restart()` is called and when the form is shown again all these methods are skipped. So I have no way to listen to anything before the form appears. What can I do to listen for form restarts? I've seen bunches of other questions about how to restart but I didn't find anything about what to do once the form reappeared again. Thanks

```
Form1() { /*skipped*/ }
void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { /*skipped*/ }
void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) { /* skipped */ }
```

Comment: You're imagining that these are skipped.  The new process runs all the usual startup code.  Please describe what made you think that these methods weren't run.

Comment: Because I set a breakpoint inside each method and they were never hit. Also, I'm using `Properties.Settings` in these methods to prefill input controls when the window loads. The input controls are blank after `Application.Restart` but they are filled in after the standard exit and start

Comment: `Application.Restart()` uses `Process.Start` to start a new process instance.  You have to configure the debugger to automatically attach to new processes.

Comment: When you restart, you break the connection between VisualStudio and the instance you were debugging. But the methods still run.

Comment: see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/24/introducing-the-child-process-debugging-power-tool.aspx